# Python: printing a dictionary with a numpy array inside

Tags: python, json

I am trying to save dictionaries to a stream so that it can be loaded up later. The issue is that when I print the dictionary with a numpy array inside, it prints with the string "array" in front of the numpy array. Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pprint

a = {"hi":"greeting","celeryman":np.array([4,3,3])}

print(a)

pprint.pprint(a)
```

The above produces the output

```
{'celeryman': array([4, 3, 3]), 'hi': 'greeting'}
{'celeryman': array([4, 3, 3]), 'hi': 'greeting'}
```

The desired output is

```
{'celeryman': [4, 3, 3], 'hi': 'greeting'}
```

which I am hoping can be read without issue by using json.load.

Do I have to write my own printer for this?

Comment: I only know how to load the desired output into python, not the one with the "array" string inside.

Comment: Are you saying the json is the issue or the formatting? If you want to persist just pickle it which can handle a numpy array just fine

Comment: I want to print the dictionary in a format that I can read in easily later, without any special characters. So I guess the formatting is the problem. Pickle is one solution yes. The other is to convert everything to a list before printing.

Comment: why do you care about the repr output?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: If you want lists why are you using numpy arrays? If you just want to persist use pickle, I was asking why seeing the array in the output is an issue

Comment: I prefer numpy arrays because what I want to print is the output of a numerical computation. I don't know what "persist use pickle" means. I didn't know about pickle before. I would still prefer having it print out in a properly formatted json so that if I send the file to someone else, he doesn't have to ask the same questions I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to assign the numpy array as list by-

```
a = {"hi":"greeting","celeryman":list(np.array([4,3,3]))}
```

and if you again want to initialise the list attached as value to the key 'celeryman' as a numpy array then-

```
a=json.load('yourfile.json')
newnplist=np.array(a['celeryman'])
```